XA transaction example in Quarkus
I am pretty new to the XA transactions and non-XA transactions stuff inside Quarkus. What I would like if somebody can show me an example how to define XA transactions inside Quarkus project.
Preferably it would be nice if it would be simple example where first something is commited into the DB (with Panache repository pattern) and after persisting the entity then message is created and sent it via Amqp reactive message to the Artemis message broker. Of course everything should happen in one XA transaction.
In this example I would like to see how the application.properties would look like and how the class which opens and commits the transaction looks like.

I have made a simple example how to instantiate and use XA-transactions inside Quarkus. Example consumes message from Artemis MQ and commits it into PostgreSQL database. Here is the link
